pass variable to JSON contains single quote
I am having the issue sending the JSON with first name and last name whenever name has single quote "'". i.e  O'Mally or O'Keef.
Single quote breaks the JSON. How do I pass fistname and lastname variables with single quote in it?
The only way I could get it work by replacing single quote with space using firstname.replace(''', ' ').  I have tried other solutions but none of them worked.
Here's code I have.
String jsonString = 
        '{' +
            '"getHostedPaymentPageRequest": {' +
                '"merchantAuthentication": {' +
                    '"name": "{!$Credential.authorize_external_' + communityAbbreviation + '.api_login}"'+',' +
                    '"transactionKey": "{!$Credential.authorize_external_' + communityAbbreviation + '.transaction_key}"'+',' +
                '},' +
                '"refId":"'+recordId+'",'+
                '"transactionRequest": {' +
                    '"transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",' +
                    '"amount":'+recordDetail.Gift_Amount__c+',' +
                    '"order": {'+
                        '"invoiceNumber":"'+recordDetail.Donation_Invoice_Number__c +'"'+
                    '},'+
                    '"customer": {' +
                        '"email": "'+recordDetail.Email__c+'"'+
                    '},' +
                    '"billTo": {' +
                        '"firstName":"'+recordDetail.First_Name__c+'",' +
                        '"lastName":"'+recordDetail.Last_Name__c+'",' +
                         '"company": "",' +
                         '"address":"'+address+'",'+
                         '"city":"'+recordDetail.City__c+'",' +
                         '"state":"'+recordDetail.State_Province__c+'",' +
                         '"zip":"'+recordDetail.ZIP_Postal_Code__c+'",' +
                         '"country":"'+recordDetail.Country__c+'",' +
                         '"phoneNumber":"'+recordDetail.Phone__c+'"' +
                    '}' +
                '},' +
                '"hostedPaymentSettings": {' +
                    '"setting": [' +
                        '{' +
                            '"settingName": "hostedPaymentReturnOptions",' +
                            '"settingValue": "{\\"showReceipt\\": true, \\"url\\": \\"'+successPage+'\\", \\"urlText\\": \\"Continue\\", \\"cancelUrl\\": \\"'+errorPage+'\\", \\"cancelUrlText\\": \\"Cancel\\"}"' +
                        '},' +
                        '{' +
                            '"settingName": "hostedPaymentButtonOptions",' +
                            '"settingValue": "{\\"text\\": \\"Pay\\"}"' +
                        '},' +
                        '{' +
                            '"settingName": "hostedPaymentStyleOptions",' +
                            '"settingValue": "{\\"bgColor\\": \\"blue\\"}"' +
                        '},' +
                        '{' +
                            '"settingName": "hostedPaymentPaymentOptions",' +
                            '"settingValue": "{\\"cardCodeRequired\\": false, \\"showCreditCard\\": true, \\"showBankAccount\\": false}"' +
                        '},' +
                        '{' +
                            '"settingName": "hostedPaymentSecurityOptions",' +
                            '"settingValue": "{\\"captcha\\": true}"' +
                        '},' +
                        '{' +
                            '"settingName": "hostedPaymentShippingAddressOptions",' +
                            '"settingValue": "{\\"show\\": false, \\"required\\": false}"' +
                        '},' +
                        '{' +
                            '"settingName": "hostedPaymentBillingAddressOptions",' +
                            '"settingValue": "{\\"show\\": true, \\"required\\": false}"' +
                        '},' +
                        '{' +
                            '"settingName": "hostedPaymentCustomerOptions",' +
                            '"settingValue": "{\\"showEmail\\": false, \\"requiredEmail\\": false, \\"addPaymentProfile\\": true}"' +
                        '},' +
                        '{' +
                            '"settingName": "hostedPaymentOrderOptions",' +
                            '"settingValue": "{\\"show\\": false, \\"merchantName\\": \\"'+donorName+'\\"}"' +
                        '},' +
                        '{' +
                            '"settingName": "hostedPaymentIFrameCommunicatorUrl",' +
                            '"settingValue": "{\\"url\\": \\"https://mysite.com/special\\"}"' +
                        '}' +
                    ']' +
                '}' +
            '}' +
        '}';
        req.setBody(jsonString);
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

Error:
Response: {"refId":"a1kRK0000XXXXXX","messages":{"resultCode":"Error","message":[{"code":"E00013","text":"Invalid Setting Value. hostedPaymentOrderOptionsmerchantName: has invalid characters."}]}}


You might want to try replacing it with an escape character e.g. ' --> '

I tried using String.escapeSingleQuotes(firstname) but that didn't work.

Please [edit] to show an example of the generated JSON and the specific error message you get, since single quotes in string values should not cause any trouble. I am wondering if this is bad behaviour on the remote end of the callout.

Thanks, Phil. I have added Error but I was not sure how to generate JSON here.

Although it would be interesting to know why you get the issue, you should let the JSON class take care of the json string generation instead of building it yourself :
Map<String, Object> jsonMap = new Map<String, Object>{
        'getHostedPaymentPageRequest' => new Map<String, Object>{
            'merchantAuthentication' => new Map<String, Object>{
                'name' => '{!$Credential.authorize_external_' + communityAbbreviation + '.api_login}',
                'transactionKey' => '{!$Credential.authorize_external_' + communityAbbreviation + '.transaction_key}'
            },
            'refId' => recordId,
            'transactionRequest' => new Map<String, Object>{
                'transactionType' => 'authCaptureTransaction',
                'amount' => recordDetail.Gift_Amount__c,
                'order' => new Map<String, Object>{
                    'invoiceNumber' => recordDetail.Donation_Invoice_Number__c
                },
                'customer' => new Map<String, Object>{
                    'email' => recordDetail.Email__c
                },
                'billTo' => new Map<String, Object>{
                    'firstName' => firstName,
                    'lastName' => lastName,
                    'company' => '',
                    'address' => address,
                    'city' => recordDetail.City__c,
                    'state' => recordDetail.State_Province__c,
                    'zip' => recordDetail.ZIP_Postal_Code__c,
                    'country' => recordDetail.Country__c,
                    'phoneNumber' => recordDetail.Phone__c
                }
            }
        }
    };

// convert map to JSON
String jsonString = JSON.serialize(jsonMap);

Unless the issue is on your endpoint, that should solve it.

Thanks, Emmanuel. I have update my complete JSON string which has "hostedPaymentSettings" as well. How do I add that to map as it has list to it?

@calo it's just a bunch of nested Map<String, Object> for the most part. Map<String, Object> for JSON objects, and List<Object> for JSON arrays. So you'd have "something" => new List<Object>{ new Map<String, Object>{"settingName" => "a thing", "SettingValue" => "other thing"}, new Map<String, Object> { ...

Also, if you know your data structure it's often a good idea to create several inner classes and create strongly-typed data to serialize. Helps a lot with visiblity

Thanks Emmanuel and Derek. That has fixed the first name and last name problem. But I am getting new error:  "The element 'getHostedPaymentPageRequest' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has invalid child element 'hostedPaymentSettings' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'merchantAuthentication' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'.

As Bartosz said it might be easier if instead of maps you'd use classes created to match your endpoints objects. Your error however is weird since the documentation lists hostedPaymentSettings as a child of getHostedPaymentPageRequest.
Try to add if you didn't the merchantAuthentication node.
